# Can a pure function use a private constant variable inside the same class?

Tags: functional-programming, pure-function

Can a pure function use a private constant variable inside the same class?

for example:

```
class TimesThousand {
  const CONSTANT = 1000;

  function calculate(number) {
    return number * CONSTANT;
  }
}
```

can `calculate()` be considered as a `pure function`?

Comment: What language is this? And yes, as written, that's a pure function.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Just a draft rough code

Comment: What do you think how would constants affect the purity of a function? Maybe don't call it "purity" but rather "[referentially transparent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_(computer_science))"

Answer (score 5):

A pure function is pure, when the return value is only determined by its input values, without any observable side effects.

So your function is pure. Since the value of `CONSTANT` is (as the name suggests) constant, the output is purely determined by the input.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function):

> a function may be considered a pure function if both of the following statements about the function hold:
>
> 1. The function always evaluates the same result value given the same argument value(s). The function result value cannot depend on any hidden information or state that may change while program execution proceeds or between different executions of the program, nor can it depend on any external input from I/O devices.
> 2. Evaluation of the result does not cause any semantically observable side effect or output, such as mutation of mutable objects or output to I/O devices.

Comment: But the first statement does not hold since in two "different executions of the program", CONSTANT may hold a different value. For example APP_NAME is a constant, but may change depending on which instance of the program is running. Am i missing something?

Comment: How would the value of `CONSTANT` ever change? It's an immutable value, meaning it can never change.

Comment: @p0lska the only way for the constant to change is for the sourcecode to change, and the two instances are running two different versions of the app. If the two instances run the same version of the app then there is no way for them to return different values.

Comment: Well if you change the source code I'd argue it's a different function which is also pure for the same reasoning. We can't expect functions to be pure after changing the code for it